# How to call function every time div reaches max-height?

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function **only once** every time the div `#blinds` reach their `max-height` at `430px`, how can I do this?

My Codepen: https://codepen.io/cocotx/pen/YzGBpVJ

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    var blinds = document.getElementById("blinds");

    blinds.style.height = event.clientY +  'px';

  });
```

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424989/javascript-listen-for-attribute-change

Comment: If you only need to do this within your existing event listener, just add the code there: `if ( parseInt(blinds.style.height) >= 430 ) { ... }`.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of [Fire an event when DOM element's computed style changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186427/fire-an-event-when-dom-elements-computed-style-changes)

Comment: Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186427/fire-an-event-when-dom-elements-computed-style-changes#comment23594000_13186427) it's possible to [catch element resizes with some trickery](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/).

Answer (score 0):

One polling way is adding the code below in your js if there are other behaviours changing the size of the element. Simply change `400` to the value you want.

```
var blinds = document.getElementById("blinds");

setInterval(() => {
  let rect = blinds.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (rect.height > 400)
  console.log(" reach 400");
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thank you Wenbo, I have tried your code but this would keep logging `"reach 400"` for as long as the div is over 430px which is not quite what I'm looking for. I would like to call the function only once every time it reaches 430px. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can add a variable to keep the previous height. An example
`
var previousHeight = -1;
setInterval(() => {
  let rect = blinds.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  if (rect.height > 400 && rect.height != previousHeight) {
    console.log(" reach 400");
  }
  previousHeight = rect.height;
}, 100);
`
Depends on your requirement, you can set the value of `previousHeight` anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    var blinds = document.getElementById("blinds");

    blinds.style.height = event.clientY +  'px';
     // i added here the condition
     if(blinds.offsetHeight > 430 /*the value you want*/){
        //call your function
     }
  });
```

Notice that this doesn't work if you use blinds.style.height instead of blinds.offsetHeight, there's a difference between using these but i im still trying to figure it out.
I would suggest to clean your code:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove',handler);

function handler(event){
   ...
   if(blinds.offsetHeight >430){
      //call your function
      ...
      //and maybe remove the listener
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove',handler);
   }
};
```

EDIT: try this code

```
function hasReachedMax(){
    var styles = getComputedStyle(blinds);
    var borderBottom = styles.borderBottom.split("px")[0]; //this is to get the number of pixels
    var borderTop = styles.borderTop.split("px")[0];
    var maxH = styles.maxHeight.split("px")[0];
    var currentDivSize = blinds.offsetHeight-borderBottom-borderTop;
    return maxH == currentDivSize;
};

function resetTrigger(){
    //the condition to reset your trigger, for example making the div element at least 5 px smaller than maxHeight

    var styles = getComputedStyle(blinds);
    var borderBottom = styles.borderBottom.split("px")[0];
    var borderTop = styles.borderTop.split("px")[0];
    var maxH = styles.maxHeight.split("px")[0];
    var currentDivSize = blinds.offsetHeight-borderBottom-borderTop;

    return maxH-currentDivSize>5;
};

//this should be part of your main code
var trigger = true;
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {

    var blinds = document.getElementById("blinds");    
    blinds.style.height = event.clientY +  'px';

    if(hasReachedMax()&&trigger){
       //call your function
        console.log("Im called now");
        trigger=false;
    }

    if(resetTrigger()) trigger=true;
        
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help :) I would not want to remove the listener as that would stop div from changing height in respective to the cursor. However when only calling function `if(blinds.offsetHeight >430){//call function}` it would keep firing for as along as the div is over 430 px. Is there a way to only call the function **once** every time it is over 430px?

Comment: i edited the answer: hope it helps you and it's what are you looking for