# Transitioning "width"property while DOM is changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I'd like to have a transition on width of a container which width of the container is equal to the width of content and content is changing by dom.

Here is a link http://jsfiddle.net/sabbasi/5xc5s08w/3/

Code from Fiddle:

```
var container = $(".container");
var nav = $(".nav");
var menu = $(".menu");

$(".sth1").click(function(){
    nav.detach();
    menu.appendTo(container);
    menu.show();
});

$("button").click(function(){
    menu.detach();
    nav.appendTo(container);
});
```

Comment: You could add a css transition, or use jquery animate.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153897/transition-element-size-caused-by-content-changes

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to set transition to .container ... but didn't work